# maven exec plugin - logback not functioning

Tags: java, maven, logback

I have a maven project which holds configuration information and has it packaged in a zip file.  I use the maven dependency plugin to unpack the contents to ${project.build.directory}/unpacked and then run the resource plugin over that to filter the contents and dump them directly to ${project.build.directory}.

When I run maven exec, my logback.xml is not being picked up.  It appears the classpath is set to ${basedir}, but I'd like it to have both ${project.build.directory}, that and test-classes, that and classes.

Anytime I try to add a classpath element, I get a configuration error.

How should I configure my pom.xml to support this and is this even possible?

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>

                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>run</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>java</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>

                    <configuration>
                        <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}</workingDirectory>

                        <mainClass>${jar.mainClass}</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

Comment: How do you invoke maven exec and how is it configured right now?

Comment: I am invoking it by attaching it to the package lifecycle I believe.  I put it in a particular profile, executable, so that I can run it by simply saying mvn clean package -Pexecutable.

Comment: By default, the build directory should be part of the classpath. How exactly is exec configured, and where is your logback.xml located?

Comment: When I run lsof, I see the project directory being included.  I originally just ocnfigured exec with just the main class, but tried adding classpath arguments to no avail.  The logback.xml that is filtered is in the ${project.build.directory}.

Comment: Can you maybe add the relevant parts of the pom xml to your question?

Comment: updated - added part of my pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the problem.

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <!-- <classpathPrefix></classpathPrefix> -->
                        <mainClass>com.stackoverflow.test</mainClass>
                    </manifest>

                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Class-Path>${project.build.outputDirectory}/unpacked/logback.xml</Class-Path>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```